# ASPXAUTH cookie always null

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

For some reason ASPXAUTH is always null, even though it does exist under FireBug Cookies tab.

```
  if (Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH");
    }
```

what gives?

Comment: Where is this code at in the pipeline of the request?  Meaning, in a controller, controller attribute, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the cookie of your application,try something like this:

```
HttpCookie appCookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

to Decrypt it, you could use:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(appCookie.Value);
```

// you can get the info using the 'ticket' object.

```
 string cookikePath = ticket.CookiePath;
 DateTime expiration = ticket.Expiration;
 bool expired = ticket.Expired;
 bool isPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent;
 DateTime issueDate = ticket.IssueDate;
 string name = ticket.Name;
 string userData = ticket.UserData;
 string version = ticket.Version;
```